# IOS Silent Remote Push Notifications not delivered to app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, silentpush

Need some help interpreting this:

I have set the background modes and remote notifications in info plist. Looking at the console logs, message arrives to the phone but it doesnt seem to wake the app. The following info shows up.

I am not able to understand The rationale : **PushDisallowed**. Can any one throw some light on what could be the cause for it. What is the policy here that is being suggested?

I have ios 15.3 installed:

**[ {name: ApplicationPolicy, policyWeight: 50.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{[pushDisallowed]: Required:0.00, Observed:1.00},]}}  ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}**

I am using Airship and my Paylod is the following(which i think matches with background silent notification requirement)

**"notification": {
"ios": {
"content-available":1
}

}**

and can see this in the phone console :

**Received remote notification request BCB8-D00F [ waking: 0, hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 pushType: Background]**

Thanks!!!

Comment: What payload are you sending?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212390/pushdisallowed-and-decision-absolutely-must-not-proceed-on-iphone-after-som

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding( I updated the post also with the payload):  I am using Airship and my Paylod is the following(which i think matches with background silent notification requirement) and can see this in the phone console :

**"notification": { "ios": { "content-available":1 }}**